# importing protobuf generated modules within packages

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

This is my directory structure.

```
.
|-- A
|   |-- B
|   |    `-- b.proto
|   `-- C
|        `-- c.proto
`-- py_gen
```

I compile the test.proto like this

```
protoc --python_out=py_gen/ --proto_path ${ROOT}/A ${ROOT}/A/B/b.proto \
       ${ROOT}/A/C/c.proto
```

and this is the results that I get.

```
.
`-- py_gen
          |-- B
          |    `-- b_pb2.py
          `-- C
               `-- c_pb2.py
```

It all works fine, and I can import each module and use the module, if I include ${ROOT}/A/B/py_gen/B and ${ROOT}/A/B/py_gen/C in my PYTHONPATH.

The problem comes when, say, module c imports b. This would translate in the generated code for c importing

```
 import B.b_pb2
```

This is what is expected, because "In Python, packages are normally determined by directory structure" (from [the protobuf tutorial](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/pythontutorial.html)). However, I cannot import module c because it does not find B.b_pb2.py. At the moment, to have it working, I have to add empty __init__.py files within the generated directories B and C.
So why there is no __init__.py in the generated directory structure? Am I forgetting something? I am very new to python, so I might be overlooking something obvious here. But reading the python [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

> The __init__.py files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages.

Answer (score 3):

Just:

```
import B.b_pb2
```

Without the `.py` ending. Also, for this to work, the `B` directory must have an `__init__.py` file in it, which can be empty. This tells Python this is a *package* directory. AFAIK protobuf won't put the `__init__.py` in there for your - but neither should it, since its goal is to just generate a single module for you.

Comment: I am indeed importing without the .py extension, that was my mistake while writing the question (I am correcting it), thanks.

Comment: Why should not it generate the package structure? It is generating the directory structure and it is aware of the dependencies of the modules.